# How to get elements of specific class starting with a given string?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of elements that have multiple classes, for example:

```
<input class="etape btn-info others">
<input class="etape btn-inverse others">
<input class="etape btn-danger others">
```

How to write jQuery-code that will allow me the following...

```
$(".etape").click(function(){
   $(this).get("the class that starts with btn-")
   // in order to store this value in a variable to reuse it later 
});
```

Comment: what i want is th get the attribute class value when the element clicked

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression or `split` the class name.

```
$(".etape").click(function(){
   var classes = $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function(v, i){
       return v.indexOf('btn') === 0;
   }).join();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LQPh6/

Comment: interesting i will try this

Answer (score 21):

You can also try:

```
$(".etape").click(function () {
    var theClass = $(this).attr("class").match(/btn[\w-]*\b/);
    console.log(theClass); 
});
```

Uses match instead of grep...

Comment: why match instead of grep?

Comment: It's the one that I know, just offering an alternative.  Either way is good.  Actually, this approach is slightly less complicated, you get the string directly without having to manipulate an array.

Answer (score 8):

```
 // Only select input which have class 
 $('input[class]').click(function(){  
   var myClass;
   // classNames will contain all applied classes
   var classNames = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);  

     // iterate over all class  
     $.each(classNames, function(index, item) {
        // Find class that starts with btn-
        if(item.indexOf("btn-") == 0){
          // Store it
          myClass = item;
        }
     });

  });
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aFmY7/)

Comment: This won't work, the class attributes do not start with `btn-`.

Comment: @undefined: oops. Just got your point while making fiddle. Updated it again. Thanks!

Comment: Good, now it returns what it should. +1

Answer (score 6):

It would probably be better to store those values in the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) attribute:

```
<input class="etape others" data-btntype="info">
<input class="etape others" data-btntype="inverse">
<input class="etape others" data-btntype="danger">
```

Then:

```
 $(".etape").click(function(){
     var myBtnType = $(this).data('btntype');
 });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mr5zn/)

Comment: this is a good idea , but my elements are generated dynamically , if there is simpler way ?

Comment: @fatiDev Since they're generated dynamically, why can't you set the data-btntype when creating the element?

Comment: what is meant is that the data btn type may be changed for the same button

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You can change it with `$(inputyouwantchanged).data('btntype', 'myNewButtonType')`.

Answer (score 2):

You could just make btn its own class. However, this will work.

```
$("div[class^='btn-']")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `$('input[class*='btn']').attr("class");`

Answer (score 2):

**I just made @Vohuman 's function to reusable one :**

```
// getClassStartsWith(classes,startswith);
// Example : getClassStartsWith( 'item w-2 h-4 hello' , 'h-' );
function getClassStartsWith(t,n){var r=$.grep(t.split(" "),function(t,r){return 0===t.indexOf(n)}).join();return r||!1}
```

Example...

**HTML :**

```
<div class="item w-2 h-4 hello"></div>
```

**JS :**

```
var $element = $('.item');
var classes = $element[0].className;
var getHeight = getClassStartsWith(classes,'h-');
```

That will return `h-4`, And if no class starts with `h-` will return `false`

**Demo :** http://jsbin.com/mijujunaca/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2):

This function can get Class, ID, Data and all kind of attributes using **regex**

```
$.fn.Get_Attr_Regex = function(Pattern,Type) 
{
    Type = Type || 'class';
    var List_Str = this.attr(Type);

    if(typeof List_Str !== typeof undefined && List_Str !== false) 
    {
        var regex = new RegExp(Pattern, "g");
        var List_Array = List_Str.split(" ");
        for(var i = 0; i < List_Array.length; i++)
        {
            if(regex.test(List_Array[i]))
            {
                return List_Array[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

To use it

```
$('.T_Header').Get_Attr_Regex('btn.*','class'); // => return class value which start with btnxxx
```

or

```
$('.T_Header').Get_Attr_Regex('btn.*','id');  // => return id value which start with btnxxx
```

or

```
$('.T_Header').Get_Attr_Regex('btn.*','data-info'); // => return data attribute value which start with btnxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

```
$('input[class~="btn-"]')
```

Comment: what i want is to get attribute class which starts with btn for the element clicked

Answer (score 1):

A class starting with `btn` and which can not be the first class:

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c9Tdx/

```
$("input[class^='btn'],input[class*=' btn']").each(function(){
     //whatever
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if($(selector).attr("class").lastIndexOf("classToStartFrom") == 0)
   return "this selector class name starts with 'classToStartFrom'";
else
   return "this selector class name doesn't start with 'classToStartFrom'";
```

The code is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone want it to achieve on page load instead of clicking the element, use following code:

```
var classes = '';
jQuery(".etape").each(function() {
    classes += $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function(v, i) {
        return v.indexOf('btn') === 0;
    }).join() + '|';
});
console.log(classes);
```

Replace "|" with other symbol that you want to join the class names with.