# Using jQuery/Javascript to assign the class name of a clicked object to the ID of an object to toggle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, performance

I have 20+ thumbnails that, when clicked, need to toggle content that corresponds to the thumbnail clicked. Thumbnails are displayed four in a row and the content that is toggled is displayed under the row. The thumbnails also have a classed based upon the content, which is all populated via a PHP array. The toggled content will have and ID that is exactly the same as the class name for the thumbnail.

My question is, how can I use jQuery to find the class names of the clicked element and then use that class name to find the correct element to toggle? So basically, I want to re-assign the class name of the object clicked to the ID of the object to toggle.

My HTML markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="thumbnail object-one">...</div>
  <div class="thumbnail object-two">...</div>
  <div class="thumbnail object-three">...</div>
  <div class="thumbnail object-four">...</div>
</div>

<div id="object-one">...</div>
<div id="object-two">...</div>
<div id="object-three">...</div>
<div id="object-four">...</div>
```

Using this JQ works, but this is inefficient as I have 20+ of these bad boys to toggle:

```
$('.object-one').click(function(){
  $('#object-one').slideToggle();
});

$('.object-two').click(function(){
  $('#object-two').slideToggle();
});

etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[View demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mj9LC/1/)**

You're using matching classes, which would be okay but something elsewhere might add or remove classes or change the order of the classes in the element, so you should not rely on that string `class="..."` being correct, therefore can't use it to identify the element you want to slide. But, we have `data()` which we can use to tell each .thumbnail which object it should target.

```
<div class="thumbnail" data-slide="object-one">...</div>
```

And find each by id corresponding to the data-slide data attribute.

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('slide')).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: ROCKSTAR! Works perfectly. I knew it was something simple. Thanks for the push in the right direction. Will mark as the answer as soon as the time limit is up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function () {
    var get = $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function (v, i) {
        return v.indexOf('object-') === 0;
    }).join();
    $('#' + get).slideToggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wWKy6/)**

With credit for the underlying function to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505745/get-element-specific-class-that-starts-with)

Answer (score 0):

Whew that's a handful of jQuery. Are you dealing with PHP created via a CMS, like Drupal or Wordpress, and that's why you are having to kinda hack your way around calling out classes and ID's?

If not why not go in and fix your problem in two steps.

1.) Edit your HTML

```
<div id="object-one" class="common-class">
<div id="object-two" class="common-class">
<div id="object-three" class="common-class">
...
```

2.) And then go edit your jQuery

```
$(".common-class").click(function() {
    // whatever code you'd like
})
```

-Cheers

Comment: No, it's PHP that I wrote. The "class name" is based upon the team member name that I'm piping through a multidimensional array. I cleanse the name and add dashes to turn it into a class/ID name.

I can't just use a common class to toggle everything because I'm toggling different content.

Comment: This doesn't help solve the problem. You've just explained how to apply a function to several elements but have not addressed how each should be set up such that they can each target another element specifically.

Comment: Which is why I asked what he was working with. It's normal to hit this kind of a snag working with CMS's. Knowing now that that isn't the case, what about using regex as a solution with jQuery? Filter for the classes you want and then apply them to their corresponding ID's. The only downside to this is the regex performance hit